# I wrote a simple http server that seems to work, but I run into issues when trying to access through browser

Tags: c, http, httpserver

The main issue I am having doesn't seem to be in the code itself, however, I posted the code just in case. First, when I run the server and use "telnet localhost 46745" in a separate terminal I get a successful connection to localhost. Then I type "GET /hello.html HTTP/1.1". The hello.html file is located in the directory where the server is being ran from. Anyway, the GET method returns both lines of code in the hello.html file. Okay, that seems to work. The issue lies when I go to firefox, and in the browser type "http://localhost:46745/hello.html", and I don't get any error messages, but the browser just spins and says "Waiting for localhost...". What are some possible issues (code or in browser) that could be causing this issue. I have googled for hours to no avail and, yes, this is a homework assignment. Thanks.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netdb.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>   /* Internet domain header */
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <sys/ioctl.h>
#include <signal.h>

#define SA struct sockaddr
#define SERVER_PORT  46745
#define MAX_LINE     256
#define BUFFER_SIZE 10000
#define MAX_PENDING  5

int  soc ;    /* socket for server */

void signal_catcher( int the_sig ) {
  printf("terminating the server socket number %d\n",soc) ;
  close( soc ) ;
  exit(0) ;
}

int main() {
  struct sockaddr_in serv_addr, clnt_addr;
  char buf[BUFFER_SIZE];
  int len, new_s, bytes_read;
  char response[MAX_LINE];
  char fileExt[MAX_LINE];
  char* token;

  /* remove socket for server when terminating */
  if( signal(SIGINT, signal_catcher ) == SIG_ERR ){
    perror("SIGINT") ;
    exit(13) ;
  }

  if( signal(SIGQUIT, signal_catcher ) == SIG_ERR ){
    perror("SIGQUIT") ;
    exit(14) ;
  }

  /* set up listening socket soc, passive open */
  if ( (soc = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0)) < 0 ) {
    perror("server: socket"); 
    exit(1);
  }

  /* build address data structure */
  serv_addr.sin_family = AF_INET ;
  serv_addr.sin_addr.s_addr = htonl(INADDR_ANY) ;
  serv_addr.sin_port = htons(SERVER_PORT) ;

  if (bind(soc, (SA *)  &serv_addr, sizeof(serv_addr)) < 0) {
    perror("server: bind");
    close(soc);
    exit(1);
  }

  if(listen(soc, MAX_PENDING) < 0) {
    perror("server: listen");
    close(soc);
    exit(1);
  }

  printf("Socket number for server = %d\n",soc);

  /* accept connection, then receive and print text */
  while ( 1 ) {
    len = sizeof(clnt_addr) ;
    if ( (new_s = accept(soc, (SA *)  &clnt_addr , &len) ) < 0 ) {
      perror("server:  accept"); 
      close(soc);
      exit(1);
     }

  printf("\nConnect from host %s, port %hd\n",inet_ntoa(clnt_addr.sin_addr), ntohs(clnt_addr.sin_port) );

  memset(buf,0x0,BUFFER_SIZE);    //  init line 

  while( len = recv( new_s, buf, sizeof( buf ), 0 ) ) {
    if (strstr(buf,"GET")) {
      token=strtok(buf," ");
      token=strtok(NULL," ");
      sprintf(fileExt,".%s",token);
    FILE *fp;
    fp=fopen(fileExt, "r");
    if (fp!=NULL) {
              send(new_s, "HTTP/1.1 200 OK\r\n\r\n", 23, 0);
              while(bytes_read=fread(response, 1, sizeof(response), fp)) {
                int length = strlen(response)-1;
                if(response[length] == '\n') {
                  response[length] = 0;
                }
                send(new_s, response, bytes_read, 0 );
                fclose(fp);
              }
        } else {
                send(new_s, "HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found\r\n\r\n", 30, 0);
              }
     }// end if strstr
 else {
  send(new_s, "HTTP/1.1 400 Invalid Request\r\n\r\n", 36, 0);
 }
  }// end while from recv

  }// end while(1)
  close ( new_s );
return(0);
}
```

Answer (score 4):

There's a few small things wrong in your response to the client. First, you're outputting `\n\n` before the `HTTP/1.1 XXX Some Status` line. `HTTP/1.1` should be first. There is no `\n\n` before it. Secondly, you're outputting `\n`s after it. The HTTP specification specifies that you should use `\r\n`, not `\n` (although Firefox should be able to handle this). Finally, for your 400 and 404 status codes, you're not returning any content. You probably should, even if it's empty.

Comment: I made those changes (reflected above), recompiled and still firefox just spins and says "Waiting for localhost..."

Comment: @legends: The responses still have no headers. While that's okay, you need one more `\r\n` than you already have to indicate that there's no headers.

Comment: @legends: `send` can fail. Try checking to see if it's sending all of the data or if it's failing (possibly part-way through).

Comment: since send sends back the number of bytes it sent I set a variable to retrieve the returned value. Turns out it is 0...how should I go about fixing that?

Comment: @legends: I'm not sure, sorry. Try another `perror`, but it may not help you. You may be able to ask another question specifically about why it's returning zero.

Answer (score 3):

The line terminator is technically CRLF ("\r\n"), not LF ("\n").

This may not be your problem, but it is certainly a problem.

Answer (score 0):

You don't say whether your server is outputting its messages like:

```
Connect from host ...
```

so that's one thing to look for. It's possible the messages are never reaching your server.

But, regardless of that, you should get yourself a copy of [WireShark](http://www.wireshark.org/download.html) (free) or another network sniffer program so you can see exactly what's going on under the covers.

This will greatly assist in debugging these types of issues.